# Programmatically change order of inline elements of a model

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I need to programmatically change the order of elements in an inline group of my model.
Precisely i need to move certain children to the top of the inline list via TCEmainHook.
Any ideas please how to achieve this without a filthy SQL query on the MM table and manipulating sorting? I tried DataHandler and manipulation the ObjectStorage, but couldn't find a solution.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid involving Extbase for this. Depending on your use case you can use either the "afterDatabaseOperations" or "processCmdmap_postProcess". The way you should do this is to listen for updates of your parent record and when it is completely done (which it is because you'll be in the post-hooks) you can re-sort your relations using whichever arbitrary rules you like.

SQL queries aren't filthy - but Extbase definitely is messy if you attempt to use it in a non-Extbase context and in particular the persistence is going to cause you some issues. Re-sorting all relations for a certain column can be done with a single query because judging from how you describe your use case (move some to top, keep others where they are) you just have to update the "sorting" column of an identified list of UIDs in a given table. You can read what the current sorting is and determine the number you need to subtract in your UPDATE query to change it to a value that's lower than the current lowest sorting value.

For example:

`UPDATE myrelationtable SET sorting = sorting - 1200 WHERE uid IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and help. And sorry for the late reply, was on holidays. I'm using now the Query Builder to update the sorting column on my mm table, works absolutely fine.